# Showing a particular date in UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeDate on the iPhone

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have an `NSString` object that contains the string `2013-02-28`. By default, the `UIDatepicker` shows the current date, but I want to show whatever date I had in the `NSString` object.

I am converting the `NSString` object into `NSDate` and I don't know how to set that date on `UIDatePicker` in `UIDatePickerModeDate`. How could I do this?  I have tried the `setDate:` method, but it's not working.

Comment: `setDate:` is exactly how you change date on a picker. Are you sure you are creating a valid `NSDate` instance? Show us some code.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you.  You likely need to turn your NSString into a NSDate before sending it to the NSDatePicker.  Keep in mind that you may need to set the Timezone of the NSDateFormater to avoid edge cases.

```
  //Given self.datepicker is your UIDatePicker 

  NSString *dateString = @"2013-03-28";
  NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

  NSDate *date = [dateFormatterGMTAware dateFromString:dateString];
  self.datePicker.date = date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)btnDateClicked:(id)sender{

    theDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0)];
    theDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    theDatePicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date];

    // ************To keep the selected date**********

    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",btnDate.titleLabel.text ];
    NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timezone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    theDatePicker.date = date;
}
```